# Subject and Predicate in 'The cackling of geese saved Rome.'

Tags: sentence-meaning, subjects, predicate

In the question

> In the following sentence separate the subject and the predicate: ***The cackling of geese saved Rome.***

I think the sentence is talking about how ***Rome*** was saved due to ***cackling of geese*** therefore the main subject should be Rome, but answers I was given are otherwise. Can someone please explain the actual meaning of sentence to me?

Comment: Geese _cackle_ - crackling is a quite different sound!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English is quite strict about word order.  In factual sentences (i.e. not questions or some other rarer forms) the subject must precede the verb.  English has no way of marking nouns that are subjects and objects, and the grammatical function of a word or phrase is determined by position.

So the subject is "The cackling of geese" and the object is "Rome". The predicate, consisting of the verb and its objects, is "saved Rome"

Semantically the "cackling" did the action and "Rome" received the action.  This is why "cackling" is the subject and "Rome" is the object.  You can say that this sentence's topic is "Rome". But the topic of a sentence can be the grammatical subject or object.  Don't confuse the topic with the grammatical subject.